# Ransack sort_link for SQL COUNT(), SUM and AVERAGE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I would like to add sort links for the following query:

```
@q = Order.group(:suburb).select("suburb, COUNT(*) as count, SUM(total) as total, AVG(total) as average").ransack(params[:q])
```

However when i use:

```
<%= sort_link(@q, :average) %>
```

The URL gets populated correctly, but no sorting is in place!
When I inspect @q.sorts, the columns are correctly there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no average column in database so it won't work like that. You could try hack this with ransacker:

```
ransacker :average do
  Arel.sql('average')
end
```

so this average will be used when average is found.

Comment: I have [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984939/ransack-sort-on-count-of-habtm-or-hmt-associated-records) somewhat related question with a bounty. Would you like to take a crack at it?